# Как зафиксировать LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть разметка елемента для ListView.  С левого края в item'e есть прогресс бар, а с правого есть кнопка и текстовое поле они тоже в LinearLayout. А вот между ними есть LinearLayout в котором есть два текстовых поля, длина текста в которых может отличатся. 
Вопрос: как можно зафиксировать этот LinearLayout так, что бы текст не вылазил на кнопку, которая справа от него, а просто происходил перенос текста на новую строчку.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip"
    >

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Progress Bar -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
            android:id="@+id/donut_progress"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            custom:donut_progress="30" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Title of package-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnBuy"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/progressbar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rihanna Love the way"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/description"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressbar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#343434"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:text="Just gona stand there and ..."
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressbar"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/progressbar" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <!-- Buy button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBuy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BUY 4:45"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />

    <!-- Short description about package -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="random text"
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnBuy"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто замените родительский элемент на `LinearLayout` с  `android:orientation="horizontal"` и последние кнопку и текстовое поле тоже в `LinearLayout` оберните, но с  `android:orientation="vertical"`

Answer (score 0):

Укажи для TextView:
`android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"`
Если не поможет, ещё можно добавить `android:singleLine="false"`

Comment: singleLine по умолчанию false

Comment: Спасибо, не знал

Answer (score 0):

Если все эти три LinearLayout внутри горизонтально ориентированного LinearLayout, то у родительского LinearLayout укажи свойство sumWeight равное 10, а у дочерних layout_weight столько, сколько тебе нужно. layout_width при этом надо будет поставить в 0dp у дочерних LinearLayout'ов. Если корневой элемент - не LinearLayout, а например RelativeLayout, устанавливай фиксированные значения ширины в dp